# RecurrenceTable with vector

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion

Mathematica can do a RecurrenceTable with a vector, here is a simple example:

```
RecurrenceTable[{x[n + 1] == 2* x[n], x[0] == {1, 2, 3}}, x, {n,  3}]
```

with output

> {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 6}, {4, 8, 12}, {8, 16, 24}}

I want to do something similar but instead of multiplying by 2 I want to multiple each element in x[n] by a different number. For example, one would think that this would work:

```
RecurrenceTable[{x[n + 1] == {1,2,3}* x[n], x[0] == {1, 2, 3}}, x, {n,  3}]
```

since Times is listable but I get an error

> RecurrenceTable::excptn: Value {1,2,3,2,4,6,3,6,9} is a numerical exception. >>

I get the same result using MapThread etc.  Thoughts?

Comment: Would `NestList[{1, 2, 3} # &, {1, 2, 3}, 3]` be acceptable ?

Comment: Try to write down your recurrence formulae ...

Comment: Although you say you see the same problem "using `MapThread`", in MMA 8 this succeeds: `RecurrenceTable[{x[n + 1] == MapThread[Times, {{1, 2, 3}, x[n]}], 
  x[0] == {1, 2, 3}}, x, {n, 3}]`.  (This expression was prompted by @b.gatessucks' answer.)

Answer (score 6):

The trick below seems to work in this simple case :

```
g[input_List] := {1, 2, 3} input 

RecurrenceTable[{x[n + 1] == g[x[n]], x[0] == {1, 2, 3}}, x, {n, 3}]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 9}, {1, 8, 27}, {1, 16, 81}} *)
```

Comment: (+1) The truly curious thing about this work-around is if you merely leave `List` out of the definition of `g`, the `RecurrenceTable` expression does not work (it returns an empty list). Tracing the evaluation reveals the problem: `{1,2,3}*x[n]` is expanded as `{x[n], 2 x[n], 3 x[n]}`, because *MMA* does not (yet) know that `x[n]` is a list at the time of expansion.

Comment: @whuber That was the whole trick !

Comment: And a nice trick it is. :-)

Comment: Thanks. All the comments have been very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the policy is on reviving dead threads, but I came across this after a similar problem and realized that `RecurrenceTable` works with vectors if you treat the equations with proper matrix calculations. e.g.

```
RecurrenceTable[{
     x[n + 1] == {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}.x[n], 
     x[0] == {1, 2, 3}
    }, x, {n, 3}]
```

gives the correct result without any intermediate functions:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 9}, {1, 8, 27}, {1, 16, 81}}
```